# Migrating from htaccess to NGINX config

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

today i move from Apache to Nginx+FPM which resulting htaccess not work anymore, i've tried htaccess to nginx converter [HERE](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) but its not 100% resulting what i want before.

My goals here (which is fullfilled with htaccess) is to send any parameter after / to index.php?menu= while theres can be args too :

```
accessing : example.com/index.php will change URL to example.com
    
accessing : example.com/test.php will change URL to example.com/test
  - server receive menu=test

accessing : example.com/fakepageaa.asd 
  - server receive receive menu=fakepageaa.asd
    
accessing : example.com/register 
  - server receive menu=register
    
accessing : example.com/welcome&args1=usa&args2=john 
  - server receive receive menu=welcome, args1=usa, args2=john
```

My working htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?menu=$1 [QSA]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

> **UPDATED**

After many try, now my full nginx config like this

```
server {
    listen      IP:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root        /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.error.log error;
    autoindex off;

    location / { 

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            expires     max;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?menu=$1;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/(.*?)/?$ /$1.php break;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    error_page  403 /error_page.php;
    error_page  404 /error_page.php;
    error_page  500 502 503 504 /error_page.php;
    
    location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php(.*)") {
        return 307 $1$2;
    }
}
```

Its almost solved my problems, currrent problems :

```
accessing : example.com/fakepageaa.asd will direct to error page
  - server should be receive menu=/fakepageaa.asd

accessing : example.com/index will change URL to example.com
  - server should be receive menu=/index


accessing : example.com/test.php will change URL to example.com/test (solved)
  - server receive menu=/test (/ can be fix using str_replace)

accessing : example.com/welcome&args1=usa&args2=john (solved)
  - server receive menu=/welcome, args1=usa, args2=john (/ can be fix using str_replace)

accessing : example.com/register (solved)
  - server receive menu=/register (/ can be fix using str_replace)

accessing : example.com/index.php will change URL to example.com (solved)
```

If anyone can help me, it would be helpfull.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused what the Apache rules you've posted have to do with the nginx rules below them. Please can you [edit] to include the rules you've tried that are causing the infinite redirect - preferably removing as many unrelated parts as possible so that you have a [mcve].

Comment: updated, sorry what im trying to do (ask help) is change htaccess to nginx format.

Comment: I don't know nginx config well enough to answer fully, but something that might help you is to fix the layout of your .htaccess rules - each group of RewriteCond lines applies only to the next RewriteRule, and does nothing alone, while RewriteEngine and RewriteBase apply to all the rules, so the current spacing is very confusing. You could then work out what each rule is doing, perhaps adding a comment next to each one. Then my universal advice: break the problem down; in this case, tackle one rule at a time.